# Ruby: NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil /snap/ruby/323/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:248:in `each'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Steps:**
run sample app:

```
rails _6.0.2.1_ new hello_app
bundle install
```

**Expected:**
rails is installed

**Actual:**
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil /snap/ruby/323/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:248:in` each'
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are trying to run an old and outdated version of Ruby on Rails with the latest version of Ruby. But Ruby on Rails 6.0 is only compatible with Ruby <3.0 (according to [this table](https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html)).

Because you want to create a new application anyway, I suggest updating Ruby on Rails to the latest version (7.1.3 at the time of writing) and try again:

```
gem install rails -v 7.1.3
rails _7.1.3_ new hello_app
```

Working with Ruby on Rails 6.0 doesn't make any sense unless you have to maintain a legacy application. But then upgrading to an up-to-date version should be your priority.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that this is definitely the problem, but you can't use ruby 3 with Rails 6.0: https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html

Comment: You erred here @Rich, the part that I included, ie. the fact that you can't use ruby 3 with Rails 6.0 **IS** the essential part from the referenced link.